# Redis error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using Redis in Node.js and when deployed on live server it started to crash with below error message:

The no of requests are more per second.

```
at Object.replyToObject [as reply_to_object] (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/lib/utils.js:7:15)
at RedisClient.handle_reply (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/index.js:319:23)
at multi_callback (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/lib/multi.js:79:43)
at Command.callback (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/lib/multi.js:116:9)
at normal_reply (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/index.js:726:21)
at RedisClient.return_reply (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/index.js:824:9)
at JavascriptRedisParser.returnReply (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/index.js:192:18)
at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:553:10)
Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/webservices/node_modules/redis/index.js:274:27)
emitOne (events.js:116:13)
Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:594:20)
```

I have written common code to open and close the Redis connections and try to reuse connections. (not sure is it correct way of reusing it).

I am using Redis "^2.7.1" and installed Redis locally on Ubuntu.

I am able to enter Redis console and see the keys stored. But not sure why its giving the above error messages very frequently. I am using pm2 module so it restarts once it crashes.

**Below is Redis Code in Node.js**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require('redis'));

// Global (Avoids Duplicate Connections)
var redisClient = null;
var redisMultiClient = null;

// Make the below functions as private
function openRedisConnection() {
    if (redisClient && redisClient.connected)
        return redisClient;

    if (redisClient)
        redisClient.end(); // End and open once more

    redisClient = Redis.createClient(6379,process.env.REDIS_URL);
    redisClient.selected_db = 1;
    return redisClient;
}

function openMultiRedisConnection() {
    if (redisMultiClient && redisMultiClient._client.connected) {
        redisMultiClient._client.selected_db = 0;
        return redisMultiClient;
    }

    if (redisMultiClient)
        redisMultiClient.quit(); // End and open once more

    redisMultiClient = Redis.createClient(6379,process.env.REDIS_URL).multi();
    redisMultiClient._client.selected_db = 0;
    return redisMultiClient;
}

function getExpiryTime(key) {
    return 120; // testing
}


module.exports = {
    /**
     * Get Key-Value Pair
     */
    getRedisValue: function (keys) {
        return openRedisConnection().mgetAsync(keys);
    },
    /**
     * Set Key-Value Pair
     */
    setRedisValue: function (key, value) {
        return openRedisConnection()
            .setAsync(key, value, 'EX', getExpiryTime(key))
            .then(function (result) {
                return Promise.resolve(result);
            });
    },

    getV2MultiRedisValue: function (keyList) {
        let redisMultiClientObj = openMultiRedisConnection();
        redisMultiClientObj._client.selected_db = 2;

        redisMultiClientObj.hgetallAsync(keyList);

        return redisMultiClientObj.execAsync()
            .then(function (results) {
                return Promise.resolve(results);
            });
    },

    setV2MultiRedisValue: function (key, redisList) {
        let expiryTime = getExpiryTime(key);
        let redisMultiClientObj = openMultiRedisConnection();
        redisMultiClientObj._client.selected_db = 2;

        for (let item of redisList) {
            redisMultiClientObj.hmsetAsync(item.key, item.value);
            redisMultiClientObj.expireAsync(item.key, expiryTime);
        }
        return redisMultiClientObj.execAsync()
        .then(function (results) {
            return Promise.resolve(results);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client.multi([commands])` doen't open multi connections, just pointing out because function `openMultiRedisConnection` is misleading.

You use mulit wrong, per reference

> client.multi([commands])
>
> MULTI commands are queued up until an EXEC is issued, and then all
>   commands are run atomically by Redis. The interface in node_redis is
>   to return an individual Multi object by calling client.multi(). If any
>   command fails to queue, all commands are rolled back and none is going
>   to be executed (For further information look at transactions).

Multi returns an individual Object and its not very good to use it again after `.exec` is called.

I don't know why you need more that one database but you are changing database with `selected_db` and on a global client variable and this is BAD! and could cause many problems!(data inconsistency, conflict, etc). 
You can use `client.select(callback)` to changed database but again it seems like a bad idea.

There is no reason for this part of code its exactly the same as not doing that.

```
 .then(function (result) {
    return Promise.resolve(result);
  });
```

You should be ok with only one database.

```
   var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require('redis'));

// Global (Avoids Duplicate Connections)
var redisClient = [];


// Make the below functions as private
function openRedisConnection( {
    if (redisClient && redisClient.connected)
        return redisClient;

    if (redisClient)
        redisClient.end(); // End and open once more

    redisClient = Redis.createClient(6379,process.env.REDIS_URL,{"db":1});

    return redisClient;
}


function getExpiryTime(key) {
    return 120; // testing
}


module.exports = {
    /**
     * Get Key-Value Pair
     */
    getRedisValue: function (keys) {
        return openRedisConnection().mgetAsync(keys);
    },
    /**
     * Set Key-Value Pair
     */
    setRedisValue: function (key, value) {
        return openRedisConnection()
            .setAsync(key, value, 'EX', getExpiryTime(key));

    },

    getV2MultiRedisValue: function (keyList) {

         let redisClient = openRedisConnection();

        //no need to open multi here....
        let multi = redisClient.multi();

        multi.hgetallAsync(keyList);

        return multi.execAsync();

    },

    setV2MultiRedisValue: function (key, redisList) {
        let expiryTime = getExpiryTime(key);
        let redisClient = openRedisConnection();

        let multi = redisClient.multi();

        for (let item of redisList) {
            multi.hmsetAsync(item.key, item.value);
            multi.expireAsync(item.key, expiryTime);
        }

        return multi.execAsync();

    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for answer..  **1** .then(function (result) {
    return Promise.resolve(result);  });  actually before the promise is resolved there is some business logic which is removed for clarity so this is ok..   **2** different db's need to check if I can merge. **3** Multi concept let me implement and get back to you asap

Comment: //no need to open multi here.... you have mentioned this comment in **getV2MultiRedisValue** function and saying `let multi = redisClient.multi();` is this correct ? just getting confused

Comment: `multi` is used to do que and  run multiple commands. Since you only do `hgetallAsync` which is only one command there is no need for multi

Comment: Redis is commonly used for cached data and not complex "business" logic. What exactly are you trying to merge... Maybe you have some logic that can run differently?

Comment: thanks i checked for almost 5 days monitoring the server no crashes happened. Your code worked.